# Error in reading a CSV file with read.table()

Tags: r

I am encountering an issue while loading a CSV data set in R. The data set can be taken from

https://data.baltimorecity.gov/City-Government/Baltimore-City-Employee-Salaries-FY2015/nsfe-bg53

I imported the data using `read.csv` as below and the dataset was imported correctly.

```
EmpSal <- read.csv('E:/Data/EmpSalaries.csv')
```

I tried reading the data using `read.table` and there were a lot of anomalies when looking at the dataset.

```
EmpSal1 <- read.table('E:/Data/EmpSalaries.csv',sep=',',header = T,fill = T)
```

The above code started reading the data from 7th row and the dataset actually contains ~14K rows but only 5K rows were imported. When looked at the dataset in few cases 15-20 rows were combined into a single row and the entire row data appeared in a single column.

I can work on the dataset using `read.csv` but I am curious to know the reason why it didn't work with read.table.

Comment: @zx8754 you mean the link is not working or the download? you can export the data to any format from Export tab in the link

Comment: Strange, now it is working, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

read.csv is defined as:

```
function (file, header = TRUE, sep = ",", quote = "\"", dec = ".", 
    fill = TRUE, comment.char = "", ...) 
read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote, 
    dec = dec, fill = fill, comment.char = comment.char, ...)
```

You need to add `quote="\""` (`read.table` expects single quotes by default whereas `read.csv` expects double quotes)

```
EmpSal <- read.csv('Baltimore_City_Employee_Salaries_FY2015.csv')
EmpSal1 <- read.table('Baltimore_City_Employee_Salaries_FY2015.csv', sep=',', header = TRUE, fill = TRUE, quote="\"")
identical(EmpSal, EmpSal1)
# TRUE
```

Comment: I tried with TRUE but still the same result. I am getting only 5083 rows imported.

Comment: I didn't notice it at first but the default for read.table is `quote = "\"'"`, whereas for read.csv it is `quote = "\"""`. That is, read.table, for some reason, presumes single quotes but read.csv presumes double quotes. Funny.

Comment: Thanks @lebatsnok. This worked. But still I didn't understand the main logic of not mentioning quote option.

Comment: in many cases it wouldn't make a difference but in your table you have lots of quoted values eg. `"Abrams,Maxine"`. for `read.table` (with default `quote` argument) this would be two different values: `"Abrams` and `Maxine"` whereas `read.csv` (with default `quote` argument) would recognize it as a single value. Then you have `ASSISTANT STATE'S ATTORNEY` and  `Sheriff's Office`  - `read.table` would take everything between these single quotes as a single quoted value, i.e `'S ATTORNEY ... ..... ..... Sheriff'`.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned, your data is imported successfully by using `read.csv()` command without mentioning quote argument. 
Default value of quote argument for read.csv function is `"\""` and for read.table function, it is `"\"'"`.
Check following code,

```
read.table(file, header = FALSE, sep = "", quote = "\"'",
           dec = ".", numerals = c("allow.loss", "warn.loss", "no.loss"),
           row.names, col.names, as.is = !stringsAsFactors,
           na.strings = "NA", colClasses = NA, nrows = -1,
           skip = 0, check.names = TRUE, fill = !blank.lines.skip,
           strip.white = FALSE, blank.lines.skip = TRUE,
           comment.char = "#",
           allowEscapes = FALSE, flush = FALSE,
           stringsAsFactors = default.stringsAsFactors(),
           fileEncoding = "", encoding = "unknown", text, skipNul = FALSE)

read.csv(file, header = TRUE, sep = ",", quote = "\"",
         dec = ".", fill = TRUE, comment.char = "", ...)
```

There are many single quotation in your specified data. And this is the reason why read.table function isn't working for you.

Try the following code and it will work for you.

```
 r<-read.table('/home/workspace/Downloads/Baltimore_City_Employee_Salaries_FY2015.csv',sep=",",quote="\"",header=T,fill=T)
```

Comment: The code worked fine. But in the syntax of `read.table` quote is mentioned as `quote = "\" ' " `. But in the code we have given as `quote = "\ " " ` . How did this work?

Comment: you didn't specified quote argument in your read.table function. and because of this , function has taken its default value `"\"'"` .when you specify `quote="\"'"`, read.table consider single quoted string as one cell. and when you specify `quote = "\""` , read.table function escape single quotation and consider only double quoted string as one cell.